# How can we update the values of injected variables after initially assigning a value in Jenkins?

Tags: html, shell, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I have injected variables `SUCCESS_COUNT=6` and `FAILURE_COUNT=0` under properties content and I have executed a shell script wherein I'm using these injected variables.

```
if [[ $A_STATUS == "FAILED" ]]
then
FAILURE_COUNT="1"
echo $FAILURE_COUNT
fi
```

`echo` shows me the value as `1`, but when I'm using this variable `FAILURE_COUNT` in the HTML table I need to send, its value is still `0` and not `1`. why isn't the variable value getting updated?

Comment: Are you doing this in a `while read` loop? Or any `while` loop you're piping to?

Comment: No, I'm not using any while loop here, I have six windows batch command through which I'm running the 6 test suites through jenkins ,for storing their success or failures counts, at the end I have written a shell script which will update the variables SUCCESS_COUNT and FAILURE_COUNT depending on whether test suite execution failed/passed. My concern is that Injected variables value not getting updated. Its still showing me as 0 which I had initially assigned under the properties content.While echoing I see the updated value but cant use the updated value of the variable elsewhere. Please help.

Comment: Can you extend the example to a self-contained complete reproducer ([mcve])?